# Is there a way to get at the generic type that another generic type extends in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an interface that is for types that can convert themselves to `IDBKey`:

```
interface IDBValidKeyConvertible<TConvertedDBValidKey extends IDBValidKey> {
    convertToIDBValidKey: () => TConvertedDBValidKey;
}
```

I then have a class that I want to accept a type that is either `IDBKey` or `IDBValidKeyConvertible`:

```
class InMemoryIndexedKeyValueStore<TKey extends IDBValidKey | IDBValidKeyConvertible<UKey>, TValue> {
    public constructor(public readonly storeName: string) { }

    private getDbKeyFromKey(key: TKey): TKey | UKey {
        return isIDBValidKeyConvertible(key) ? key.convertToIDBValidKey() : key;
    }

   ...
}
```

But this doesn't work as written because `tsc` gives this error about `UKey` in the class declaration:
`Cannot find name 'UKey'`

Is this because of [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) TypeScript issue where generics cannot be "higher kinded types?"  Or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional type like this:

```js
type ConvertedKey<TKey> = TKey extends IDBValidKeyConvertible<infer UKey> ? UKey : TKey;

private getDbKeyFromKey(key: TKey): ConvertedKey<TKey> {
  return this.isIDBValidKeyConvertible(key) ? key.convertToIDBValidKey() : key;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! That seems like it gets me part of the way there, and it reminded me about the `infer` keyword which was something I completely forgot about! However, one small hitch seems to remain from my original question: how do I write the generic type description in the class declaration? It doesn't work with just `UKey` as in my question, and if I stick an `infer` up there as well, I get an error saying "`infer` declarations are only permitted in the 'extends' clause of a conditional type"

Comment: I guess I can just make the class declaration use `IDBValidKeyConvertible<any>` and not lose any type safety?

Comment: I think this is what you want: `IDBValidKeyConvertible<ConvertedKey<TKey>>`

Comment: That's a good idea, one I certainly didn't think of. Unfortunately, assuming I understood your suggestion properly, that gives me this error:
`class InMemoryIndexedKeyValueStore<TKey extends IDBValidKey | IDBValidKeyConvertible<ConvertedKey<TKey>>, TValue>`

`Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite`

Comment: Ah sorry yes, you were correct to use `IDBValidKeyConvertible<any>` in the class generic